# mouseleave with @HostListener not firing always in angular directive

Tags: angular

I have an angular directive where on mouse enter I am showing a tooltip and on mouse leave hides the tooltip. but Sometimes the mouseleave is not firing so that the tooltips are not hiding. see the image below. and below is the code for my directive. I am kind of new to angular. so Can anyone help here please?
[image]

```
 import { Directive, Input, ElementRef, HostListener, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { ToolTipFactory, ToolTipRequester } from '../services/api/models/common.models';
import { ProductService } from '../services/api/product.service';

@Directive({
  selector: '[tooltip]'
})
export class TooltipDirective {
  @Input('tooltip') fieldName: string;
  @Input() placement: string = 'top';
  @Input() productType: string;
  @Input() UOM: string;
  @Input() horizontal: boolean = false;
  @Input() fieldvalues: string;
  @Input() model: string;
  tooltipTitle: string;
  tooltip: HTMLElement;
  ToolTipReq: ToolTipRequester;
  tooltipElement: any;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2, private productService: ProductService) { }
 
  @HostListener('mouseenter', ['$event']) onMouseEnter(e: MouseEvent ) {
    if (!this.tooltip) {
      this.ToolTipReq = ToolTipFactory.createNew(this.productType);

      this.ToolTipReq.fieldName = this.fieldName;
      this.ToolTipReq.UOM = this.UOM;
      this.ToolTipReq.FieldValues = this.fieldvalues;
      this.ToolTipReq.Horizontal = this.horizontal;
      this.ToolTipReq.Model = this.model;
      const s = this.productService.getToolTip(this.ToolTipReq).subscribe(result => {
        if ((result.Message != undefined && result.Message != '') || (result.Title != undefined && result.Title != '')) {
         this.show();
        }
      },
        error => {
          s.unsubscribe();
        },
        () => {
          s.unsubscribe();
        }
      );


    }
  }

  @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event']) onMouseLeave(e: MouseEvent) {
    if (this.tooltip) {
      this.hide();
    }
  }
  
  show() {
    this.create();
    this.setPosition();
    this.renderer.addClass(this.tooltip, 'ng-tooltip-show');
  }

  hide() {
    this.renderer.removeClass(document.body, 'ng-tooltip-show');
    this.renderer.removeChild(document.body, this.tooltipElement);
    this.renderer.removeChild(document.body, this.tooltip);
    this.tooltip = null;
  }

  create() {
    this.tooltip = this.renderer.createElement('div');
    this.renderer.appendChild(
      this.tooltip,
      this.tooltipElement
    );

    this.renderer.appendChild(document.body, this.tooltip);
    this.renderer.addClass(this.tooltip, 'ng-tooltip');
    this.renderer.addClass(this.tooltip, `ng-tooltip-${this.placement}`);
  }

  setPosition() {
    
  
  }
}
```

Comment: can you check if these directives are not overlapping on each other in HTML?

Comment: No, I do not think so it is overlapping.
<div _ngcontent-woh-c128="" class="ng-tooltip ng-tooltip-top ng-tooltip-show" style="top: 246.25px; left: 525.99px;"><span><span class="tooltip-title">Total Sound Power Limits:</span><br><span class="tooltip-body">   Min. = 50 dB
   Max. = 155 dB</span></span></div><div _ngcontent-woh-c128="" class="ng-tooltip ng-tooltip-top ng-tooltip-show" style="top: 236.5px; left: 778.734px;"><span><span class="tooltip-title">Total Sound Power Limits:</span><br><span class="tooltip-body">   Min. = 50 dB
   Max. = 155 dB</span></span></div>

Comment: can you provide the stackblitz ?

Answer (score 0):

Please go through the link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13911
And yes when we move very fast then sometimes the Mouseleave never fires. so as an work around what I did is calling the tooltip hide method after a timeout of 2-3 secs in the mouseenter event itself.

```
 window.setTimeout(() => {
                if (!this.stillHovering) {
                  if (this.tooltip) {
                    this.hide();
                  }
                }
              }, 650);
            }

@HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
    this.stillHovering = false;
    if (this.tooltip) { this.hide(); }
  }
```